# libperl5.20 rxvt-unicode-256color Ubuntu 14

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I want to install new version of rxvt-unicode-256color (with clipboard suppport), but on my system have perl 5.18 which is not compatible with new version of rxvt.

I'm tried to use perlbrew. But again I get error that perl-base is 5.18 when I'm trying to install libperl or rxvt.

So how can I install new version of perl (5.20+) and rxvt on Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I found a newer version of rxvt on launchpad, which does not conflict with my current perl version anymore. Here is the link:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/rxvt-unicode-256color/9.19-1

Just in case that the link went down, I've also uploaded the .deb file onto Dropbox: https://db.tt/D990X6nd

You can use `dpkg` to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i rxvt-unicode-256color_9.19-1_amd64.deb
```